# How do I replace gedit 3.06 with gedit 2.30.4?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, gedit

I have some problem. I have installed gnome 3, and now I have gedit 3.0.6 version. I need to replace it by gedit 2.30.4 version. Any suggestions?

Comment: gedit 2.30 is gtk2+ based - you've upgraded to gtk3+ libraries.  I think you going to struggle to do this since gedit has large dependencies on gtk2+ libraries.  It might just be easier to run a VM with a 11.04 guest.  Why do you need to go back to gedit 2.30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been pointed out, gedit 2.x uses GTK2 and gedit 3.x (supposedly) uses GTK3 so I wouldn't expect it to be easy to downgrade gedit and make it work without uninstalling Gnome 3 and installing Gnome 2 libraries.

Technically, you may be able to download Gnome 2 source code and either compile it with a custom prefix so all Gnome 2 libs go into say /opt/gnome2 and don't mix with the Gnome3 libs or even statically link gedit executable so it's a standalone blob which doesn't use any external libraries. But I think it goes way beyond the amount of effort I'd be willing to spend on this :)

Which brings us to the question: what are your reasons to use gedit 2.x? It's not a particularly stellar or unique editor. Are there any other editors which can be used instead? As a personal suggestion: kate is very good.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Gedit 2.x version has plugin which makes work with windows-1251 encoding very comfortable. Gedit 3.x hasn't such plugin and I can't find information how to customize default encoding in gedit 3.x version. That's why I tried to downgrade this editor.

Comment: Try Kate, seriously - among other things it can work with different encodings